# How to increase the font size of the Xcode quick help popup?

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 14 and I am wondering how I make the text of the Quick Help bigger. In the settings I can only seem to change the editor font. This is a screenshot of the Quick Help popup showing:

[image: Xcode screenshot]